# forEach function in my apps script says undefined: trying to autocomplete form dropdown

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to autocomplete a dropdown so it generates the list when triggered, but I get the mistake in the forEach section. The part where i left the text was to work out other issues. The forEach section says it is undifined but I have made sure to complete all brackets and semicolons... maybe i missed something.

```
  var ssID = "1sQGIXhtH_EqWCmMckUMDP1JjlBdRRJ--UJePtJ7T99c";
  var formID = "1hv53EFDAkFJ5qEA23UA68c76uHdyXHkanBmIjCpRWL4";

  var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("MAESTROS");
  var form = FormApp.openById(formID);

function main(){
  var labels = wsData.getRange(1, 1, 1, wsData.getLastColumn()).getValues[0];
  
  labels.forEach(function(label,i){
      Logger.log(label);
      var options = wsData
                    .getRange(2,i+1,wsData.getLastRow()-1,1)
                    .getValues()
                    .map(function(o){ return o[0]})
                    .filter(function(o){ return o !==""});
      Logger.log(options)
    });
}

function updateDropdownUsingTitle(title,values) {
  
  //var item = form.getItemById (1449588801);
  //Logger.log(item.getTitle());
  var items = form.getItems();
  //Logger.log(items[0].getId().toString());
  var titles = items.map(function(item){
    return item.getTitle();
  });

var pos =titles.indexOf(title);
if(pos !== -1){
var item = items[pos];
var itemID=item.getId();

  updateDropdown(itemID,values);
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var labels = wsData.getRange(1, 1, 1, wsData.getLastColumn()).getValues[0];
```

It should be:

```
var labels = wsData.getRange(1, 1, 1, wsData.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
getValues() // return [[]], it has to have ().
```